# How do I fire an event when a form is submitted by something other than the submit button?

Tags: jquery

Consider the following code:

**HTML**

```
<a href='#' id='the-button'>Submit</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#the-button").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#the-form").submit();
});

$("#the-form").submit(function(e) {
  //stuff here
});
```

when the '#the-button' is clicked and the form is submitted, the 'submit' event handler does not fire. Is there any way to attach an event handler to a form so that it fires even if it is not submitted via the submit button?

Comment: Your code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/pVbsJ/

Comment: Do you have your code wrapped in a document.ready function?  If not that's probably the reason why the event handler isn't getting attached to your element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `$("#the-form").submit();` to `$("#the-form").trigger('submit');`

Edit: However, like @wirey said, the code you posted should work, unless there is some other code interfering.

Comment: Hm, hadn't heard of trigger before. +1

Comment: What's the difference between `.submit()` and `trigger('submit')`?

Comment: @wirey: my understanding is that not all browsers fire onSubmit when the form is submitted through javascript (i.e. `form.submit()`). Some only fire onSubmit when activated by the user.  jQuery's .trigger() method is supposed to simulate the user activation. The `$("#the-form").submit();` call seems to work in some browsers, like Chrome 23, but not all.

Comment: @Johann weird.. jQuery docs mention nothing about `.submit()` not working in any browsers. - since he is using jQuery's `.submit()` and not the Native Javascript `.submit()` http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Anyway, you're right that the OP's code should work as is assuming there's no other code interfering. I'll edit my answer.